# SQL query empid assigned with manager id need replace manager id with name

Tags: sql

I have table which contain`empid` having assigned manager id, where ever empid having managerid need to replace manage id with manager name.

table structure as below

```
EMPID MANAGERID EMPNAME MANAGERNAME
001   NULL      ABC     NULL
002  001        DEF       001
```

Need an output as  below

```
EMPID MANAGERID EMPNAME   MANAGERNAME
001   NULL      ABC       NULL
002   001        DEF       ABC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How DBMS affects this case ? (Just Curious) Even if it does a generic solution (When possible ) must be used so that we can change underlying DBMS without rewriting the queries.

Comment: @Amit: most probably the DBMS dos not matter in this case. But very often knowing the DBMS helps in providing better answers. The question doesn't really include enough information actually e.g. where does `dfc` come from? Or is this a kind of hierarchy which might need a recursive query (which is DBMS dependent)? Or does "replace" mean some string replacement is needed which again is DBMS dependent.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I get your point. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

if Manager Name is in same table :

```
select t1.empID, t1.Name, t2.Name as Manager from table t1, table t2   
where t1.empID=t2.ManagerID
```

Or try this

```
select t1.EMPID, t1.MANAGERID, t1.EMPNAME, t2.EMPNAME as Manager from testTable11 t1 
left join testTable11 t2 on t1.MANAGERID=t2.EMPID
```

Comment: Please don't use the old fashioned implicit joins in the where clause. Using an explicit `JOIN` in the `FROM` clause is much more robust against accidentally forgotten join conditions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Agreed, hope My 2nd Query won't disappoint You :)

Comment: Those two are not equivalent. The second one is an outer join, the first one is an inner join.

Comment: Its not working here am providing the sample data for your understanding data available in single table 1.0001 ros abc.com null 2.002 son cbc.com null 3.003 child cnd.com 001 4.004 subc ndd.com 002 form above data need an out as 1.001 ros abc.com null 2.002 son cbc.com null 3.003 child cnd.com ros 4.004 suc ndd.com son

Comment: @Roshan: So the data is in same table, then try 2nd Query now, I've just changed..

Comment: Thanks you all I have got it through the below query as    select e.empid,e.empname,(select mgr.empname from emp mgr where mgr.empid=e.empid) as manager from emp e

Comment: @SonalPM: Thanks you to all of you, for support and answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't share the Table structure, I had to assume it for your question. Consider you have below table structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE employee(emp_id varchar(5) NOT NULL,  
emp_name varchar(20) NULL,  
dt_of_join date NULL,  
emp_manager_id varchar(5) NULL,  
CONSTRAINT emp_id PRIMARY KEY(emp_id) ,  
CONSTRAINT emp_manager_id FOREIGN KEY(emp_manager_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id));
```

In that case you can use below query to list employees with their manager's name:-

```
SELECT a.emp_id AS "Emp_ID",a.emp_name AS "Employee Name",  
b.emp_name AS "Manager Name"  
FROM employee a, employee b  
WHERE a.emp_manager_id = b.emp_id;
```

Note: Here it is assumed that all the employees have manager id associated with their record.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment please try below query,

```
 SELECT a.emp_id AS "Emp_ID",a.emp_name AS "Employee Name",  
    a.emp_manager_id AS "Manager Id",
    b.emp_name AS "Manager Name"  
    FROM employee a LEFT JOIN employee b  ON a.emp_manager_id = b.emp_id;
```

Comment: Its not working here am providing the sample data for your understanding data available in single table 1.0001 ros abc.com null   2.002 son cbc.com  null  3.003 child cnd.com 001 4.004 subc ndd.com 002 form above data need an out as  1.001 ros abc.com null    2.002 son cbc.com null 3.003 child cnd.com ros 4.004 suc ndd.com son

Comment: @Roshan Please see my new query. I just tested it on my machine it should work for you now..

Answer (score 0):

You need a self (outer) join on the same table:

```
select e.empid, 
       e.empname, 
       e.managerid, 
       mgr.empname as managername
from employee e
  left join employee mgr on e.managerid = mgr.empid;
```

Comment: Thanks you all I have got it through the below query as    select e.empid,e.empname,(select mgr.empname from emp mgr where mgr.empid=e.empid) as manager from emp e